# Elasticsearch: generic tokens combinations

Tags: jquery, generics, elasticsearch, token, combinations

suppose that I have a string composed by three tokens: abc def ghi.

I would like to perform a query to retrieve the exact matching and its variations like:

abc ghi def (tokens in any ordering)

abc def (missing token)

abc def jkl ghi (any tokens inserted between my desired tokens)

azc dzf gzz (tokens with an error in any number of its chars)

that is, I want to retrieve documents that have the exactly tokens, its variations and its orthographic errors.

I tried a match phrase prefix query but it doesn't perform a regexp in the initials tokens, just in the last token.

I tried regexp query but it doesn't perform a slop between the tokens.

Could someone suggest me something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I index a document like the one below with no special settings, analyzers, etc:

```
PUT my_index
{
    "text": "abc def ghi"
}
```

Then a simple `match` would do the job

```
# exact search
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "abd def ghi"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> matches with score 0.26574233

# tokens in any ordering
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "abd ghi def"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> matches with score 0.26574233

# missing token
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "abd def"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> matches with score 0.2169777

# any tokens inserted between my desired tokens
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "abd ghi jkl def"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> matches with score 0.093538016

# tokens with errors in any number of its chars
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "azc dzf gzz",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
=> matches with score 0.25571066
```

Comment: Were you able to try this out?